# iAd banner pushes content of screen upwards when appearing at bottom

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

I'm having trouble with a bug I just can't seem to understand how to squash. I have an iAd banner at the bottom of my screen. When it loads in the simulator, it frequently pushes my images, labels, etc up as if it's resizing my background imageview; and therefore, all my constraints

Here is the code for my iAd banner:

```
func bannerViewWillLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {

}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    self.adBannerView?.hidden = false //now show banner as ad is loaded
}

func bannerViewActionDidFinish(banner: ADBannerView!) {

}

func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
    return willLeave
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    self.adBannerView?.hidden = true
}
```

Now this problem only sometimes happen. You can see the difference at the bottom of my screen when comparing the two:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSSlF.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bE6tO.jpg

Any help would be greatly appreciated as to why this is occuring.

Comment: I got the same thing here!! Even though I removed it from its superview!! I am using Objective-C in Xcode 7.0 ... Did you manage to solve it? The Google adMob is working pretty good, but not the iAd Banner View from Apple??

Answer (score 1):

For some reason `banner.hidden = true` upsets the view. Instead, make the banner transparent: `banner.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()`